# Html.BeginForm action routing to index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

This is probably something simple. I have two actions in my controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var m = new MyModel();
    return View(m);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(MyModel model)
{
    //do stuff
    return View(model);
}
```

In my strong-typed index view I'm setting up the form with BeginForm() :

```
// action, controller, routeValues, FormMethod
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "MyController", new { model = this.Model }, FormMethod.Post))
{ %>

    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstProperty)%>
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondProperty)%>        
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>

<% } %>
```

The problem is, when the form renders it's ignoring the action, yielding this:

```
<form id="form1" action="./" method="post">
```

Why is it ignoring the specified action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have more than one form on the page...

Comment: Yup, that's what it was. I'd created a new Site.Master forgot it added a form wrapper.